# Limiting an RDD size

Tags: apache-spark

I have an RDD as follows:

```scala
rdd
   .filter { case (_, record) => predicates.forall(_.accept(record)) }
   .toDS()
   .cache()
```

It basically filters down an RDD after applying a predicate.

The issue I have is this... Some of my data set RDDs are massive and predicates may be empty meaning that we attempt to cache an entire data set.

Instead what I'd like to do is always `limit` the size of the data set before I cache it.
I've tried placing a limit as follows:

```scala
dataSet
   .filter { case (_, record) => predicates.forall(_.accept(record)) }
   .limit(10000)
   .toDS()
   .cache()
```

but I get OOM errors. It looks to me like the partitions are being overloaded before the limit is applied.
Therefore I'm wondering if there is some way for the limit to be applied to the partitions. So effectively filtering would be paused once we reach the limit.

Scaling out further isn't an option as these data sets are too big

Comment: from where you creating dataset db, file or other, and what is predicates from which you are checking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should likely look into [sampling the rdd](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.RDD.sample.html).  If you provide a consistent seed you will get a consistent result.  You likely don't want "withReplace". This will run faster than using limit.  Sample does work on the entire data but filters as it goes reducing the data set.

> `RDD.sample(withReplacement, fraction, seed=None)`
>
> Parameters:
> withReplacement - bool can elements be sampled multiple times
> (replaced when sampled out)
>
> fraction - float expected size of the sample as a fraction of this RDD’s
> size without replacement: probability that each element is chosen;
> fraction must be [0, 1] with replacement: expected number of times
> each element is chosen; fraction must be >= 0
>
> seed - int, optional seed for the random number generation

Relevant code links ([rdd.sample](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/rdd.html#RDD.sample)), ([subclass that does actual work work](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/rddsampler.py).)

Comment: If you found my answer helpful could you upvote it? If you are comfortable marking it as the answer and you have time that would be appreciated.